# WebBrowser stops responding on a particular webpage, but IE doesn't

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

If you make a WinForms app and add a `WebBrowser` control and navigate to this page:

http://www.llrx.com/features/deepweb2010.htm

The application will stop responding. IE, Chrome and Mozilla won't. Any idea of "what am I doing wrong"?

Comment: Are you talking about webbrowser control?

Comment: Yes I am. I'll make that clear in the question.

Comment: What version of IE is installed?  If you have IE8 or IE9 installed, be aware the Web Browser Controls lock to IE7 compatmode by default. To change that, you need to set FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lines of CSS below are freaking it out:

```
/* MSIE PC */
#logo a { background-image: expression(this.runtimeStyle.backgroundImage = "none", this.innerHTML = '<img src="http://www.llrx.com/themes/llrx/images/logo.gif" border="0" alt="' + this.innerHTML + '">'); }
#tagline a { background-image: expression(this.runtimeStyle.backgroundImage = "none", this.innerHTML = '<img src="http://www.llrx.com/themes/llrx/images/h2.gif" border="0" alt="' + this.innerHTML + '">'); }
```

You're assigning a node's `innerHTML` to an image's `ALT` attribute but the `innerHTML` contains unescaped HTML so you end creating some very funky HTML like:

```
<img alt="<img alt="<img alt="<img alt="
```

A screenshot might show better:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

He's right.

```
            WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
            wb.Parent = this;
            wb.Visible = true;
            wb.Navigate("C:\Test.html");
```

With the smallest form of the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <base href="http://www.llrx.com/" />
    <style type="text/css" media="all">@import "/themes/llrx/style.css"; #beta2fix a:hover {color: #000;}</style>
</head>
<body>

<div>
    <h1 id="logo"><a href="/">Test</a></h1>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Be damned if i know why (yet).